# Creation of SSH keys in Ansible and immediate use of them

Tags: git, ssh, ansible

I would like to create SSH keys in Ansible and immediately used them. So far, I have this playbook that creates SSH keys, instructs some users to add them to their Github account, and then I try to clone a git repo based on the created keys. However, I get the following error, `Permission denied` from Github's side. My guess is that the process running Ansible maybe did not updated the `ssh-agent` with the new key.

Does this seem plausible and is there any way to force Ansible to add a new ssh key to the ssh-agent?

```
---
- name: Setup Github
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    ssh_key_filename: id_ed25519_github

  vars_prompt:
    - name: code_folder
      prompt: Folder to contain code
      private: false
      default: "~/Code"
  
  tasks:
  - name: Creation of folder structure
    file:
      state: directory
      path: '{{code_folder}}'

  - name: generate SSH key '{{ssh_key_filename}}'
    openssh_keypair:
      path: "~/.ssh/{{ssh_key_filename}}"
      type: ed25519
      state: present
      force: no

  - name: Display public key
    command: "cat ~/.ssh/{{ssh_key_filename}}.pub"
    register: pub_key

  - name: Show to stdout public key
    debug: msg="{{pub_key.stdout}}"

  - name: Add Github Key
    debug:
      msg:
        - 'Login to Github'
        - 'Click on Settings/SSH and GPG Keys'
        - 'Add new authentication key'
        - 'Paste the content of the key from above'

  - name: Add your public key to Github
    pause:
      prompt: Press enter once you have added your key

  - name: Git Config Setup - Email
    pause:
      prompt: Please enter your Github email
    register: email

  - name: Git Config Setup - Name
    pause:
      prompt: Please enter your name
    register: name

  - name: Setup Config
    command: "git config --global {{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - user.name "{{name.user_input}}"
      - user.email "{{email.user_input}}"

  - name: Clone OTP
    git:
      clone: true
      dest: "{{code_folder}}/otp"
      remote: upstream
      repo: git@github.com:erlang/otp.git
      version: maint
```

Comment: If you just created it, it won’t be in your GitHub account, so it won’t be allowed from GitHub side.

Comment: Would it be possible to instead use the public Git url for otp? I.e. `repo: https://github.com/erlang/otp.git`

Comment: Add `key_file: "{{ ssh_key_filename }}"` to the `ansible.builtin.git` module call.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε The script creates the key, instructs the user to go to Github and add the key to their Github ssh keys, and then the user must press some key so that the Ansible script continues knowing that the key was added to Github. This means that Github should not reject the keys... I think the issue could be that the ssh agent has not yet picked the new key